# How ADF Security performs actual authentication?

Tags: oracle, security, weblogic, oracle-adf

I would like to make benefit of ADF security features by enabling it in my application, the application's identity store is a database table. How is it possible to let ADF authenticates users based on this identity store?

How are enterprise roles, and application roles mapped to the user defined in database?

I am using WebLogic as a web container.

Comment: What is the question? There are many links out there to try - without more information, no one can help

Answer (score 0):

To use enterprise roles and users from database you need a configuration like described in this blog:

http://soadev.blogspot.co.uk/2010/04/sqlauthenticator-simply-best.html

Every enterprise role name will be automatically converted to Application Role. So you won't need a an explicit mapping.